# Binding ControlTemplate child to DependencyProperty on a custom control not working

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, dependency-properties

My UserControl looks like this:

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="ExtendeTextBoxStyle">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Grid>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding ErrorMessage, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"  x:Name="ErrorMessage" Foreground="Red" ></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="textbox"   Style="{StaticResource ExtendeTextBoxStyle}" ></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

Code behind

```
 public string ErrorMessage
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ErrorMessageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ErrorMessageProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ErrorMessage.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ErrorMessageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ErrorMessage", typeof(string), typeof(CustomControl), new PropertyMetadata("x"));
```

Now in my main page, I am trying to pass the value for `ErrorMessage` like this

```
 <local:CustomControl ErrorMessage="My Error message"></local:CustomControl>
```

All looks good to me but `ErrorMessage` value is not getting displayed. What am I missing here?

My complete application is available [here](https://filebin.net/2g8pm38fsgiumtdu) to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RelativeSource TemplatedParent` is wrong, because `ErrorMessage` is not a property of the templated TextBox.

Use an ElementName binding like this

```
<UserControl x:Name="self" ...>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding ErrorMessage, ElementName=self}" .../>
```

---

Usually the Bindings in a ControlTemplate are TemplateBindings like

```
<TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" .../>
```

You would than set the Text property of the styles TextBox like

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource ExtendeTextBoxStyle}"
         Text="{Binding ErrorMessage, ElementName=self}" .../>
```

Comment: gives an error for me -->
 Unknown member 'AncestorType' on element 'RelativeSource'

Comment: It's UWP, right? Please don't tag UWP question with WPF.

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. Corrected now

Comment: My code after I made modifications you asked
 <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding ErrorMessage, ElementName=CustomControl}"  x:Name="ErrorMessage" Foreground="Red" ></TextBlock>

Comment: Your answer is correct and I am able to make it work. But is there any way to avoid setting an error message on the Text property of TextBox. I have to use that text property for other purposes.

Comment: The first solution also works. No idea where you went wrong with that.

Comment: This is how I tried your first solution https://filebin.net/up82n76xsiuu98w6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213965/discussion-between-none-and-clemens).

Comment: You forgot `<UserControl x:Name="CustomControl" ...>`

Comment: yap. that was it. :D

Comment: You should have seen a data binding error message in the Output Window in Visual Studio during debugging.